# Help proving that $(Y - X)' = X\cup\; Y'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

This is my first time taking a discrete course, never been that strong in math. We just got to proofs and am really struggling with this question.

> For all sets X and Y that are subsets of a universal set U, show that
> $(Y - X)' \; = X\cup\; Y'$

I know that $Y-X = Y\cap\;X'$
But since I've got the complement of $Y-X$, I'm unsure how to proceed in the proof.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 1):

To prove: For all sets $X$ and $Y$ that are subsets of a universal set $U$, show that
$$
(Y - X)' \cap = X \cup Y'
$$

We know that $$Y - X = Y \cap X'$$
But since we have the complement of $Y - X$, we use De Morgan's Law:
$$
(Y - X)' = (Y \cap X')'
$$
Applying De Morgan's Law again, we get:
$$
(Y \cap X')' = Y' \cup (X')'
$$
Since the complement of a complement is the original set, $$(X')' = X$$ Thus:
$$
(Y \cap X')' = Y' \cup X
$$
Comparing this to $X \cup Y'$, we have:
$$
X \cup Y' = X \cup (Y')
$$
By the commutative property of union, $A \cup B = B \cup A$, we can rewrite this as:
$$
X \cup (Y') = (Y') \cup X
$$
Thus, we conclude that:
$$
(Y \cap X')' = X \cup Y'
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider an arbitrary element $x$ in $(Y - X)'$.

$$\begin{align*}
&x \in (Y -X)' \\[0.3cm]
\Longleftrightarrow \,\,\, &x \notin (Y-X) \\[0.3cm]
\Longleftrightarrow \,\,\, &x \notin Y \,\, \vee \,\, x \in X \\[0.3cm]
\Longleftrightarrow \,\,\, &x \in Y' \,\, \vee \,\, x \in X \\[0.3cm]
\Longleftrightarrow \,\,\, &x \in (X \cup Y') \\[0.3cm]
\end{align*}$$

Hence, $(Y -X)' = (X \cup Y')$